# how can i output the right date using strtotime?

Tags: php

I want my $curdate to add 2 days every time i clicked to button.
but i always get the output "01-01-1970"

i always get that output.

here is my code:

```
$curdate = date('m-d-Y');
$mydate=getdate(strtotime($curdate));
switch($mydate['wday']){
    case 0: // sun
    case 1: // mon
        $days = 2;
        break;
    case 2:
        $days = 2;
        break;    
    case 3:
        $days = 2;
        break;
    case 4:
        $days = 3;
        break;
    case 5:
        $days = 4;
        break;
}
echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime("$curdate +$days days"));
```

i want my output to be date today plus 2 days.

can anyone help me please?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$curdate = date('m-d-Y');` will give a date formatted with `-` separators, and with month before day.

According to [PHP's documented rules](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) strtotime() will recognise dates with a `-` separator as UK/European format dates, so a date like `01-15-2016` will be invalid

**EDIT**

```
$curDate = new DateTime();
echo $curDate->add(new DateInterval('P2D'))->format('m-d-Y');
```

$curdate

Comment: The right code would be to stop hacking between string representation and unix timestamps, and do all your calculation using timestamps (or even better, DateTime objects) and only format for display purposes

Comment: here is the right code for that


echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime("+$days days"));

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime`'s first argument is text string with some date changes starting from now (without second argument), e.g:

```
echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime("+6 days"));    // add six days to now date
```

So you don't need to use `$cur_date` variable in it:

```
echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime("+$days days"));
```

Comment: If the answer solved your problem ( which it appears to have done ) then you should accept the given answer